# Whitespace, actionscript, and regex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a text file that needs to be parsed correctly. The text file looks like this:

```
[header]
   [header 2]
   [ header3 ]
```

I can grab these headers by doing so

```
var expression:RegExp = /[ [a-z0-9 ]+ ]/igxm;
var items:Array = text.match(expression);
```

But I would also like to remove the white space from before and after the brackets, so the headers can align against the left edge. Also, for [ header3 ], I would like to remove the white space inside the brackets, before "h" and after "3". What would be the correct regex for something this? Thanks in advance.

tone

Comment: do you need to convert 'header 2' to 'header2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var expression:RegExp = /\[[ ]*([a-z0-9 ]*[a-z0-9]+)[ ]*\]/igxm;
var header:String = text.replace(expression, "$1");
```

This assumes you only have one match per-line (you run the same regexp over each line). If you want to run through the whole string, you can run the same regex with String.match() and then use the snippet above to extract the group.

Comment: sure, I just took another look and changed the regex (since it would match trailing whitespaces too eagerly)

Comment: Hey Clement, it seems that the brackets are being stripped out on the replace. How can I maintain them?

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out. Thanks so much for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

and a lil bit other way:

```
var str:String = "[header]\n   [header 2]\n   [ header3 ] ";
var tmpArr:Array = str.match(/\[\s*\w+\s*\d*\s*\]/gm);
for (var i:int = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++ ) {
    tmpArr[i] = tmpArr[i].replace(/(\[)\s+(\S.+\S)\s+(\])/g, '$1$2$3');
}
trace(tmpArr.join('\n'));
/*-outputs-
[header]
[header 2]
[header3]
---------*/
```